# Insert into php database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to insert into a table `media` and a column `membro`, a member name when he is logged in and he has uploaded an image/video, with no luck, this is my code that I put in submit.php:

```
<?php $fbme = $_SESSION['jigowatt']['username'];?>
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['jigowatt']['username'])) {
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO media (membro) values ('$fbme')");
}?>
```

I don't like to waste your time as I love this site, but some tips will be thanked.

Comment: Your `session_start()` placement is wrong. It should be at top the document (before the `$fbme` line).

Answer (score 1):

Try your code with little difference  like this :

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
 $fbme = $_SESSION['jigowatt']['username'];?>
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['jigowatt']['username'])) {
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO media (membro) values ('$fbme')");
}?>
```

Comment: You need to start_session() no matter what, not only if $_SESSION is not set.

Comment: Where the problem is ? in query or session value ?

Comment: @MadsBjaerge But you can check whether the session is already started or not.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman, no you check whether the $_SESSION var i set, which is not the same as having it actually started...

Comment: I can't test your code just now.can you tell me the error ? or what you expect from code that is not working

Comment: This code uploads a image/video, from guests or members, and post it liki in 9gag, i am trying to insert into a table media and a column membro, a member name when he is logged in and he has uploaded an image/video, so i can put his name on that post.

Comment: Please put your media table structure on your question area.I think you are confuse about relationship of media and user ? right

Comment: http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/2594/0yrb.png here @MahmoodRehman media is the table, membro is the columm.

Comment: I think you need to update not insert .in short and simple tell me from where did you inserting other fields ? why one field in insert query ?

Answer (score 1):

Start `session` at the start of the code and the use `session` after that

```
     <?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); ?>
       <?php $fbme = $_SESSION['jigowatt']['username'];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on your session so it can be accessed:

```
session_start();
```

Throw this at the top of your page, unles you already have it on an include further up the page. If you already have; 
Everything looks in order from a first glimpse, if there is an under-laying problem with the MySQLI Driver within your code, try turning on the error reporting

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
```

Or even it's because you have not specified the database link:

```
$DB = new mysqli("","","","");
mysqli_query($DB,"");
```